# invalid LOC header (bad signature)

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

In the Android studio, after opening my project I am getting this message

```
Cause: invalid LOC header (bad signature)
```

and when I sync my gradle this error pops up

```
 Could not initialize class kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.load.kotlin.DeserializedDescriptorResolver
```

I have latest gradle plugin and kotlin plugin version installed.
Till now I have tried -

1. Cleaning project
2. Invalidate cache and restart
3. Deleted caches manually
4. Downgrading my gradle version

But nothing seems to be working. Please help

Answer (score 0):

The error was due one of cache file not opening, it was throwing `CacheOpenException`. I went through lot of answers on SO but none of them worked, later i found this answer telling to **delete .gradle file** from **users directory** and after waiting a whole lot of time for gradle sync, the error was finally resolved!